ydata_profiling not working with Python 3.9
I have a Jupyter notebook.  Why would this snippet work when the Python kernel is 3.8.12 but not when I use 3.9.19?
import pandas as pd
from ydata_profiling import ProfileReport
On 3.9.19, the error is:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ydata_profiling'
ydata_profiling version 4.8.3

3.8.12? Not 18? What is the error? What version of ydata_profiling?

Oops, yes, sorry, 3.8.12.  I have updated the question with more information

Run in a new cell in the notebook where you want to import %pip install ydata_profiling and see what it says. If it installs, restart the kernel and try. You may need to refresh more than the kernel to fully test.

always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback. It will be also more readable in question, and more people can see it - so more people may help.
